# How to specify schema while DB connection in typeORM for oracle DB

Tags: typescript, oracle, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am a beginner with TypeORM, I am using oracle DB with node js in the backend. I have managed to connect the db with typeORM using `createConnection()`. But I am not able to specify the schema while creating connection

Another way is adding schema to each entity like this

```
@Entity({schema:"Users"})
```

But I cant use this as the schema will be changing according to the dev/test/prod environment. Only way can be specifying it during creating connection

I checked typeORM connection options documentation https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/connection-options.md It has `schema` option for postgres and MySQL but it doesn't specify any options for oracle.

Comment: can't you use an environment variable to configure this?: `@Entity({schema:"Users"})` ?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, "user" and "schema" are effectively the same thing. In most cases (unless you are a DBA or have other specific elevated privileges) you must connect directly to the user/schema you want to work with. There is no way to change user/schema once your connection is established; you would have to reconnect with new credentials.

If you *do* have elevated privileges to work with objects in schemas other than the one you connected to (e.g. `create any table`), you can do that by fully qualifying the object name (e.g. `schema_name.table_name`) in your DDL, DML, or SQL. You would not need to reconnect first.

In cases where there is a shared application schema/user, proxy user access can be configured by the DBA that will allow you to connect *as* another user using your personal credentials and avoid having to share common passwords or keys, but you would still be connected to a specific schema/user.

Comment: If there is access to the node-oracledb connection, the [`connection.currentSchema`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propconncurrentschema) attribute can be used instead of explicitly changing SQL statements.

Comment: Yes - this would change the default schema for purposes of fully qualified names, but would not change the user/schema to which you are actually connected. You would still need elevated privileges to access any schema other than the one you are connected to.

Comment: I tried using `schema : schema_name` in typeorm createConnection() and it seems to query the table like this `schema_name.table_name` . But oracle gives an error saying "table or view does not exist" so I might not have access to use object of another schema as @pmdba mentioned

Comment: By default you will not have access to any other schemas. Access must be granted by the other user/schema account, or by a DBA.